# Grouping a select list (optgroup) in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to make a list of grouped things in CakePHP 3, to create a grouped list of things in a select list in a form. I'm not sure if I am missing something or if I'm expecting too much of Cake and should be doing more myself.

I have a controller called `Issues` and a self-referencing column called `RelatedIssues`.  Each `Issue` belongs to a `System`, and it's the systems I want the issues grouped by.

In my `IssuesTable.php`:

```
$this->belongsTo('RelatedIssues', [
    'className' => 'Issues',
    'foreignKey' => 'issue_id'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Systems', [
    'foreignKey' => 'system_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

...and in my `IssuesController`'s `edit` method:

```
$relatedIssues = $this->Issues->RelatedIssues->find('list', [
    'groupField' => 'system_id'
]);
```

When I get to the drop-down list, items are grouped by `system_id` as specified, but I cannot figure out how to get them grouped by the `System`'s title field.  Is this even possible, or do I have to write a nice nested `foreach` structure to do this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be (can'try it now):

```
$relatedIssues = $this->Issues->RelatedIssues->find('list', [
    'groupField' => 'system.title'
])->contain('Systems');
```

Comment: If I add the contain() but leave 'system_id', I get "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'title' in order clause is ambiguous". It's entirely possible I've done something odd elsewhere.

Comment: It seems you added an order clause somewhere. Maybe in one of your Tables file

Comment: Thanks, @arilia, I did indeed have an order clause set on all 'findAll' queries in the controller.  I didn't think it would have an adverse effect.  But I do want to sort this list, any ideas how I would go about it?

Comment: I should see the code, but I guess that you just need to change `->order(['title']=` in `->order(['Systems.title']=` somewhere

Comment: Thanks again @arilia. One last question, and this might be stretching what Cake can do: is it possible to write a query so that both the Systems (the optgroup) AND the Issues are sorted ("title ASC")? I seem to be able to do one (as above) or the other (with 'order' => 'RelatedIssues.title ASC' in find() options), but not both.

Comment: pass an array of fields to your order clause

Comment: I'm really late, but yes @Vaughany it works! I just did this and it works:    $categorias = $this->Chamados->Subcategorias->find('list', [
      'groupField' => 'categoria.nome', 'valueField' => 'nome']
      )->contain(['Categorias'])->order(['Categorias.nome' => 'ASC', 'Subcategorias.nome' => 'ASC']);

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following, is more clear:

```
$relatedIssues = $this->Issues->RelatedIssues->find('list', [
        'contain' => ['Systems'],           
        'order' => [ 'Systems.title' => 'ASC', 'RelatedIssues.title' => 'ASC'],         
        'groupField' => function($entity) {
            return $entity->system->title;              
        }
]);
```